# memcached issue and load average

Tags: php, apache2, memcached

I have a blog with like 800 000 visits per day and sometimes I can have like 5000 / 6000 person on a post so I decide to use memcached to have a lowest load average ( to reduce query on my database ) the problem is when I have many people on a post ( 2000 / 3000 ) my load average on my server can go to 80 / 100 and I think memcached is not doing his job 
Here my code I use to store / read in memcached

```
function setPostInCache($post_id, $post_array){

    $memcached = new Memcached(); 
    $memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
    $memcached->set('POST_'.$post_id, $post_array, time() + 360);
}

function getPostInCache($post_id){
    $memcached = new Memcached(); 
    $memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

    return $memcached->get('POST_'.$post_id);
}
```

I don't know if the problem come from here or do I need to use singleton pattern ?

Comment: I think the `set` method waits for a time duration in seconds (and not a date like you seems to pass). You should remove the `time()` in the 3rd parameter. Also you can test to cache with Redis

Comment: Why are you suspecting memcache? What are the symptoms? I mean what debugging you have done to come to this stage?  are memcache logs showing something?